# Can the Magento swagger UI also show XML sample data and allow XML requests?

Tags: swaggerui

We are using the swagger UI at `ourshop.example.com/swagger` to the the API and generate examples.

While the Magento API perfectly supports XML data (incoming and as result), the swagger UI only allows `application/json` format.

Is there way to tune the integrated swagger UI to also support XML?

Comment: Swagger is for REST API and the magento API doesn't support XML data natively. Are you referring to SOAP api?

Comment: I am talking about the Request BODY, and it does support XML. just set content-type: application/xml or accept-type: application/xml

Comment: Found this one: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/583